# How can you write a docker daemon that can kick off other docker containers as needed?

Tags: docker

I've seen several options for how a docker container can communicate directly with its host system but they all seem kind of sneaky. For instance, it appears one can start a container and bind (using -v) the in-container docker executable to the host's docker executable. One can send messages to the host using a networking protocol. It also appears that the --privilege flag might help as well.

Each of these methods appears to have drawbacks and security concerns. My bigger question is if this architecture is even the best approach.

Our goal is to have a docker daemon process running, polling a database being used as a queue. (I know this is frowned upon in some ways but our traffic is very low and internal. Performance for this sort of queue is not an issue.) When the docker daemon detects that there is work to be done, it kicks off another docker container to handle that work. That container dies when it is finished. Each container belongs to a "system" and will run load on that system. Each system can only have one container running load on it.

Is this a paradigm that makes sense?
Would the daemon be better off as just a host-level process? A Python script, for instance, instead of a docker container?
Is Docker meant to be used this way? Am I just missing where, in the Docker documentation, it tells me how to do this?
Are my "sneaky" ideas above not so sneaky, after all?

I understand there is an opportunity for opinion here. I am looking for some concise best practices.

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred solution that I've seen the most is to install the docker binaries in a container, and then mount the /var/run/docker.sock into the container. The Dockerfile I have for something similar looks like:

```
FROM upsteam:latest
ARG DOCKER_GID=999
USER root
# install docker
RUN curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
# app setup goes here
# configure user with access to docker
RUN groupmod -g ${DOCKER_GID} docker && \
    usermod -aG docker appuser
USER appuser
```

And then it's run with:

```
docker run -d --name myapp -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock myapp
```

This would be the most efficient solution since you remove the network bandwidth. And it removes any network vulnerabilities, either from an open port, or from including the TLS cert inside your container which could accidentally leak with something like a lost backup.

Comment: Ok. That sounds like a good solution. Are there any advantages to this over similarly binding `/usr/local/bin/docker` so that my container can call docker commands that will be executed outside of the container? I will look further into docker networking.

Comment: Mounting the docker executable into the container still runs it inside the container, it's nearly identical to copying the binary inside the container except it doesn't get updated when you upgrade the binary on the host. The main advantage of that is you would run the same version of docker. The main disadvantage is that you don't get all the shared libraries and other prerequisites that come with installing the application inside the container, significantly increasing the chances of execution errors.

Comment: by the way: there is an official docker image called `docker` that contains already the docker client. No need to have your own docker file.

Comment: Still need your own Dockerfile if you want an application other than just Docker in your image. For me it's easier to start with the other application and add Docker than it is to start with Docker and install the other application, since the same Docker install can be use verbatim in every scenario.